# See the log of a jar in android (adb)

Tags: java, android, logging, jar

i've a question: how can i see the log of a library, which is used as jar into my android app, in the `logcat`?
Is is also possible to redirect it to a file stored into the sd of the android?

To make it clear, the jar libary uses:
`import java.util.logging.Logger;`
where the logger is created as follow `private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StreamingEngine.class.getName());`

and then the various level as `logger.info("..");`

if i check the `logcat` i don't see anything from that library.
is it my fault (that i don't know how to query logcat) or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper which does both logging action

```
public class Log
{
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MAIN_LOGGER"); 

    // info
    public static void i(String tag, String message)
    {
        // logcat
        android.util.Log.i(tag, message);

        // log4j
        logger.info("[" + tag + "] " + message);
    }

    // TODO other levels
}
```

It can be improve of course.

Comment: My bad, you don't have control over the jar. Do you know where is your logger config file ?

Comment: actually i've control on the jar, but i would like to keep it as it is. As "my logger config file" what are you refering to?

Comment: The config file that controls where your logs land, stdout, in a file

Comment: in android there's no such config file, or there's?